# How to push undefined or null to the back of an array with sort?

Tags: javascript, sorting, logic

I have 3 items in an array and each of those items have a property called `distanceFromUser` which is just a `number`. Two of those objects have `undefined` for that property.

If I run `items.sort((a,b) => a.distanceFromUser - b.distanceFromUser);` the two object with `undefined` or `null` get put first in the array. How can I get them to go in the back of the array?

Comment: (...) ¦¦ NUMBER .MAX_VALUE assuming distance can't be 0. Few lines more otherwise

Comment: If all values are numbers it sorts just fine, I just need to know what to do if the value is undefined or null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the values for `undefined` or `null` and sort them to the end of the array, while perserving the order of the distance with a chained approach.

```js
var items = [{ id: 1, distanceFromUser: undefined }, { id: 2, distanceFromUser: 1 }, { id: 3, distanceFromUser: 2 }, { id: 4, distanceFromUser: 5 }, { id: 5, distanceFromUser: 1 }, { id: 6, distanceFromUser: undefined }, { id: 7, distanceFromUser: null }, { id: 8, distanceFromUser: null }];

items.sort(
    (a, b) => 
        (a.distanceFromUser === undefined || a.distanceFromUser === null) -
        (b.distanceFromUser === undefined || b.distanceFromUser === null) ||
        a.distanceFromUser - b.distanceFromUser
);

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly shorter approach with [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) (does not convert to `Number` in advance as [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) is doing).

```js
var items = [{ id: 1, distanceFromUser: undefined }, { id: 2, distanceFromUser: 1 }, { id: 3, distanceFromUser: 2 }, { id: 4, distanceFromUser: 5 }, { id: 5, distanceFromUser: 1 }, { id: 6, distanceFromUser: undefined }, { id: 7, distanceFromUser: null }, { id: 8, distanceFromUser: null }];

items.sort(
    (a, b) => 
        !Number.isFinite(a.distanceFromUser) - !Number.isFinite(b.distanceFromUser) ||
        a.distanceFromUser - b.distanceFromUser
);

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! How does this know to put undefined at the back? If you do not mind explaining a little bit more.

Comment: the check `a.distanceFromUser === undefined` returns `true` or `false`, which in numerical context is `1` or `0`, which is exactly what needed as return value for sorting with delta.

Comment: @NinaScholz This does not catch `null`. I would suggest to change `===` to `==`.

Comment: So 1 - 1 would be 0, wouldn't that make it shove to the front of the array. Sorry kind of confusing. Or it would be a negative number putting in the front still. Unless I am confused on how sort works.

Comment: @TaylorAustin 0: keep order, < 0: put a to the front, > 0: put b to the front.

Comment: @SVSchmidt, now with check for `null` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your compare function accordingly. See below. Note that I used `== null` which also checks for undefined (while `===` would not). Other proposed solutions using the or operator (`a.distanceFromUser || ...`) or similar are also considerable, but error-prone if *distanceFromUser* is 0.

```js
let items = [
  { distanceFromUser: 1 },
  { distanceFromUser: 23 },
  { distanceFromUser: undefined },
  { distanceFromUser: 12 },
  { distanceFromUser: 2 },
  { distanceFromUser: 9 },
  { distanceFromUser: null },
];

items.sort((a, b) => {
  if (b.distanceFromUser == null)
    return -1;
  if (a.distanceFromUser == null)
    return 1;

  return b.distanceFromUser - a.distanceFromUser;
});

console.log(items);
```